# Block default button action with in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have one question. This is probably easy task but I am trying to overthink this.
I have such situation:

```
<Button
 className={favorites ? styles.active : styles.outlines}
 onClick={() => addToFavorites({ id })}
 variant='outline'
>
```

This button is adding a product as favourite. But i want to prevent page from scrolling. 
The addToFavorites({ id }) is passed from props.
Can i do something like this:

```
 const addFav = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };
```

and then

```
<Button
  className={favorites ? styles.active : styles.outlines}
  onClick={e => addToFavorites({ id }, addFav(e))}
  variant='outline'
>
```

Right now it is workning, but not sure if this is valid solution

Comment: yes, it is correct.

Comment: You can use `disabled` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass `addFav(e)` as an argument to `addToFavorites`. Just call it directly after `addToFavorites`:

```js
<Button
  className={favorites ? styles.active : styles.outlines}
  onClick={e => (addToFavorites({ id }), addFav(e))}
  variant='outline'
>
```

Answer (score 2):

One another way to do it.

```
<Button className={favorites ? styles.active : styles.outlines} onClick={e => addFav(e,{id}))} variant='outline'>

const addFav = (e,id) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   addToFavorites(id);
};
```

Comment: but this way i'm overwriting id

Comment: but how? can you tell me?